# How would i create a NFT smart contract that pays the artist & the consultant 10% of the sale price?

Tags: nft

I am new to programming; learning & doing at the same time, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, NFT's are not holding any data about sales. They are only holding who is the owner? (which is an address called **owner**) and who can transfer that contract? (series of addresses called **approved**). In the nature of NFT, there's no way to handle transfers. Other contracts that are consuming NFT's can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an ERC-721 contract that allows for this. Multiple NFTs are stored on each ERC-721 contract, and all NFTs on that contract will follow the same rules.

A good place to start might be to read through the SuperRare contract.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x41a322b28d0ff354040e2cbc676f0320d8c8850d#code

Comment: Thanks for answering  I will try this out